# Save values from multiple forms

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-admin` framework (v3.2). I am trying to save values using `FormDataConsumer` of multiple forms to an array of objects. I am iterating through an array of objects and for each item I am generating `SimpleForm` where I can change some data of specific item.

```
msgs !== null && Object.keys(msgs).map((index) =>
{
   return <SimpleForm record={msgs[index]} resource="msg" toolbar={null} key={index}>
             <FormDataConsumer>
                 {({ formData, basePath, ...rest }) => formData &&
                     <div {...rest}>
                        <TextInput source="_id" {...rest} />
                        <SelectArrayInput source={`publish.users.${selectedWH}`} choices={transformToObject()} {...rest} />
                       {setNewData(formData)}
                     </div>
                 }
            </FormDataConsumer>
   </SimpleForm>
 })
```

The issue is that `formData` saves only last active form. I need it to save data of every form that is present in `msgs` array.

Any ideas how can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.